# Why does datetime.today.minute doesn't give the actual minutes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python. Recently, I have encountered, that while using "datetime.today().minute" gives me o/p by adding 30. When I'm commenting the -30 part that time the output is +30 of what the recent minute is, if I keep the -30 part then it gives the correct reselt. Why is that?

**Code :**

```
from datetime import datetime
odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 ,13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29 ,31, 33, 35, 37, 39 ,41, 43, 45, 47 ,49 ,51 ,53 ,55 ,57, 59]
odd_min = datetime.today().minute #- 30
print(odd_min)
#print("\n")
if odd_min in odds:
  print("Odd min")
else:
  print("Not odd min")
```

**O/P :**

```
48

Not odd min
```

**Expected O/P:**

```
18

Not odd min
```

When I'm subtracting 30 it gives the correct result. But I wanna know why it doesn't gives the correct output.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the code you show. You mention something about 30 minute offset, but that doesn't seem like it would have any effect on determining if a minute is odd. Can you clarify what your actual issue is, perhaps modifying the code to actually demonstrate the problem?

Comment: 48 is not and odd number. How is that the wrong answer? Also your code works perfectly but, why are you checking oddity with a list of odd values?

Comment: What time zone are you in? What timezone is the computer in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your profile says you're from India, and the timezone in India has an UTC offset of +5h30, so it looks like datetime does not return your local timezone.

You could set the offset yourself like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

datetime_now = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
odd_min = datetime_now.minute
```

Otherwise you can just use your own solution and subtract (or add) 30 from the time. The time will not be your correct local time, but since your use case only cares about the minutes, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: code]

Your code is correct it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Try it in w while loop so you can see it in real time. Your commented out 
`#- 30` has no effect at all as it is a comment.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
while True: 
    now = dt.today().minute 
    print(now) 
    if now %2 == 0: 
        print(f'{now} is even')
    else:
        print(f'{now} is odd')
```

I should explain that the `%2 == 0` is just a shortcut to getting even or odd values. Im having a hard time editing this for some reason. sory about that

Answer (score 0):

It is because of timezone. You might be running your code on a system which is in IST like timezone which has +5:30 time delta.

Use 
`odd_min = datetime.utcnow().minute` instead of `odd_min = datetime.today().minute`